# Excel VBA macro:

Tags: vba, excel, date

I want to split quarterly the dates from a year (with some colors).

Right now I have a macro for 2 years only, but I want to make it automatically for every year. (ex: with Red color: between date 01/01/YYYY-01/05/YYYY..... and so on)

This is what did:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="01/01/2015", Formula2:="01/05/2015"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    End With

     Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="30/04/2015", Formula2:="01/08/2015"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 7461287
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

     Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="31/07/2015", Formula2:="01/01/2016"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 6750207
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With



      Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="01/01/2016", Formula2:="01/05/2016"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    End With

     Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="30/04/2016", Formula2:="01/08/2016"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 7461287
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

     Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="31/07/2016", Formula2:="01/01/2017"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 6750207
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

The result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed03V.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh - it that case you need this:

```
 Sub demo()
 Dim r As Range
 For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
      If IsDate(r) Then
          Select Case Month(r)
               Case 1 To 3
                   With r.Interior
                       .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
                       .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
                   End With
               Case 4 To 6
                    r.Interior.Color = 7461287
               Case 7 To 8
                   r.Interior.Color = 7461287
               Case 9 To 12
                   r.Interior.Color = 6750207
          End Select
        End If
 Next r
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the code add

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 Const DesiredYear = "2017"  'change this for each year you want
```

Then change lines like this:

```
  Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="01/01/2015", Formula2:="01/05/2015"
```

to

```
  Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
    Formula1:="01/01/" & DesiredYear, Formula2:="01/05/" & DesiredYear
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But i need to make this macro for every data from a year that i add, and i have data from 2015,2016.... 2020+. (i don't want for just an year)